# How to install an action camera bullet hd jet gt on a magicwork helmet?

Tags: sports, compact-cameras, gopro, extreme-sports

I have an action camera Bullet hd jet gt [image: bullet hd jet gt]

and a helmet [image]

What's the best way to install an action camera on a such a curved surface?
Default binding with 3M come off and it seems that simple default solution can be dangerous for a camera.

Also I wish to avoid creation of additional holes in the helmet.

Comment: Is it compatible with a GoPro mount? It looks quite similar in that photo. If so, there are a range of GoPro helmet mounts available.
eg GoPro vented helmet strap mount. http://gopro.com/camera-mounts/vented-helmet-strap-mount

Comment: Assuming this is being used for video, rather than photography, you may get more suggestions in http://avp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

At first glance you could thread cable ties through the vent holes on the side of the helmet to make a loop (get them from the electrical section of any hardware store).

From there you could use additional long cable ties or straps mounted to the curved camera base (that came with the camera) to pass through the previously made side of helmet loops.

It won't look pretty, but it could work.

Comment: Don't forget that cable ties can be chained together to make longer ones.